# Remove the IE 9 image link box

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, web, internet-explorer-9

On my website http://www.andytechguy.com/ I have a linked image on the top of every page that leads to the home page. When I am looking at the same page in IE 9 or some other versions of IE it appears to have a box of blue or purple around it. How do I remove this box?

Comment: You just need to remove the default border - `#big_header img { border: 0; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `border-style`

```
img {  
   border-style: none;
}
```